# Issues with "force user" on Samba 4.7 + Active Directory authentication

Tags: linux, unix, samba

We have a environment with a Samba 4.7 with couple shares that uses Active Directory as authentication mode and a Oracle application drop some files so users get it through those shares.

We have a specific share that needs to keep permisions from everything created there as a unix user (oracle - ID 1001), so I set the "force user" on the share, and it dont allow access for any user on the folder.

The folder permissions are 0700, user oracle, ID 1001.

I set the folder 777 to try out, and it works, created a file, then i check the IDs owner to the files created through Samba, looks like Samba is forcing user "oracle" from Active Directory (there is also a user with this name there) instead of forcing the local unix user.

Any idea how to fix it?
Found some ideas like set order on nsswitch.conf like "files winbind" but seems like Samba is ignoring this.

```
[test_acess]
comment = test
path = /shares/test_acess
public = yes
writable = yes
browseable = yes
force user = oracle
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
valid users = Domains\\Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue
"winbind use default domain = true"
Need to turn it off or